# How do I change the edge style between an mxCell and mxPoint in mxgraph?

Tags: java, swing, classcastexception, edges, jgraphx

I am trying to draw an edge with specific edge style, other than the default one. The problem is that I am drawing an edge between a cell and a point so that the edge appears as if coming from a cell to space in the graph.

```
edge = graph.insertEdge(parentCell, null, label, myCell,null);
```

I get exception:

```
"java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mxgraph.util.mxPoint cannot be cast to com.mxgraph.model.mxICell"
```

when I use this code:

```
mxGeometry geoCell = myCell.getGeometry();
mxPoint termPoint = new mxPoint(geoCell.getX() - (120 - (offset)), geoCell.getY() + 100);
graph.insertEdge(parentCell, null, "", myCell, termPoint, "edgeStyle=elbowEdgeStyle;elbow=horizontal;orthogonal=0;");
```

I am using JGraphX 1.10. Is there something I can replace the point with that wouldn't error and give the appearance of the edge connecting to space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the terminal point on the geometry of the edge, you can't use the point as a source terminal as it's expected to be a cell (see exception):

```
edge.geometry.setTerminalPoint(termPoint, true);
```

If you are trying to implement a space between the terminal and the edge you can also use the `STYLE_PERIMETER_SPACING` for the vertex or one of `STYLE_SOURCE/TARGET_PERIMETER_SPACING` for the edge.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was trying to do. Thank you.